# how to get string from user and save it?

Tags: java, android, string

I found a project in github about location tracker.and I want to change it.
How do it work?
You install this application in your device.
and from another device you send a message to your device (your message must be Where are you?)(that device that you installed application before). when you send this message , after 1 minutes you receive a link that show the current location.
https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker(link of project)
Now I want to send any message . not limited to send just where are you?
Now I want to get string from user to save and then compare then IF  there are equal send the location link.
In this activity I must get string to save.
   here is the code:

```
 public class LocationTrackerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
 }
```

and here :

```
  public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {    
  LocationManager lm;
  LocationListener locationListener;
  String senderTel;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{        
    //---get the SMS message that was received---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str="";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        senderTel = "";

        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            if (i==0) {
                //---get the sender address/phone number---
                senderTel = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            } 
            //---get the message body---
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();                 
        }

        if (str.startsWith("Where are you?")) {             
            //---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
            lm = (LocationManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

            //---request location updates---
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                    60000, 
                    1000, 
                    locationListener);

            //---abort the broadcast; SMS messages won’t be broadcasted---
            this.abortBroadcast();
        }
    }                         
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {

            //---send a SMS containing the current location---
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(senderTel, null,
                    "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + loc.getLatitude() + "," +
                            loc.getLongitude(), null, null);





            //---stop listening for location changes---
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);                
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
            Bundle extras) {
    }
}
}
```

in this code it compare with Where are you ?

```
    if (str.startsWith("Where are you?")) {             
            //---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
            lm = (LocationManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

            //---request location updates---
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                    60000, 
                    1000, 
                    locationListener);
```

The point is that I am new with android. I don't which key word help me to search about my problem can help me.
please help 
thanks in advance

Comment: A search on EditText could be fruitful.

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: sry for my bad question @selva